# Fullpage.js - Can I move through whole page with a down/up arrow key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I have a simple question. Can I scroll sections **and** slides using **the same** arrow key?

For example, I have a page with 3 sections and 3 slides in one of them. I would like to navigate through all screens (5 screens in total) using only down/up arrow key.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you capture the key event yourself and handle this through the fullpage.js API?

Comment: Sure I can do that. I ask about any other options, which I could have missed :)

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. You can disable the default key events by using the fullPage.js option `keyboardScrolling:false` and then binding yourself the keys you want with the methods you want, such as [`$.fn.fullpage.moveSetionDown`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#movesectiondown) or [`$.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#moveslideright).

Take into account that by using `keyboardScrolling: false` you will also disable other combination of keys, such as space, shift + space, page up, page down, home, end... 
You can take a look at all those key bindings [in the code itself](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/dist/jquery.fullpage.js#L1849).

Also, if you want to use the mouse wheel to also scroll through all the page you can make use of the [Scroll Horizontally extension](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scroll-horizontally.html#firstPage).

Comment: thanks, I'll use this solution. Actually I'm using Scroll Horizontally extension, so everything's great.
Btw. thanks for your work! Fullpage.js is a great tool :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this for all elements, through which you want to navigate:

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
               $('button').click(function () {

               $(".element1").stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(".element1")[0].scrollHeight }, 1000); //autoscroll to end of element1 on click on button    

               $(".element2").stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(".element2")[0].scrollHeight }, 1000); }); //autoscroll to end of element2 on click on button
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that's not what I was looking for